# React Native maps: Custom marker is moving as the map is panned

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

**Summary**
On loading the map, we are retrieving the marker locations from the backend and displaying it on the map. This works without any issues.

As the user pans the map, we are supplying new markers to the map, on doing this, some markers are behaving strangely, i.e the marker flies to a another markers location (See attached screen recording). This seems to happen when the markers are being re-rendered i.e when new markers data is supplied to the map.

[Video link](https://imgur.com/4cxEdYe)

**Reproducible sample code**

```
import MapView, { Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
export default function MyLocationScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState([
  {
    "_id": "64426c74288dd1003fed873b",
    "address": "15/11, KG Halli, D' Souza Layout, Ashok Nagar, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560001, India",
    "category": "Schools",
    "categoryId": "640033def717a5003f680844",
    "createdAt": "2023-04-21T10:59:00.363Z",
    "icon": "svgIconImage",
    "iconName": "School",
    "location": "15/11, KG Halli, D' Souza Layout, Ashok Nagar, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560001, India",
    "locationCoordinates": {
      "latitude": 12.971598258355552,
      "longitude": 77.59456252679229
    },
    "name": "Business school, benguluru"
  },
  {
    "_id": "64426c74288dd1003fed873b",
    "address": "123 Main Street, City, State 12345, Country",
    "category": "Restaurants",
    "categoryId": "640033def717a5003f680844",
    "createdAt": "2023-05-15T08:00:00.000Z",
    "icon": "svgIconImage",
    "iconName": "Restaurant",
    "location": "123 Main Street, City, State 12345, Country",
    "locationCoordinates": {
      "latitude": 40.123456789,
      "longitude": -70.987654321
    },
    "name": "Delicious Eats"
  },
  {
    "_id": "64426c74288dd1003fed873c",
    "address": "25 Park Avenue, New York, NY 10001, USA",
    "category": "Hotels",
    "categoryId": "640033def717a5003f680845",
    "createdAt": "2023-05-15T08:00:00.000Z",
    "icon": "svgIconImage",
    "iconName": "Hotel",
    "location": "25 Park Avenue, New York, NY 10001, USA",
    "locationCoordinates": {
      "latitude": 40.748817,
      "longitude": -73.984819
    },
    "name": "Luxury Hotel"
  }
]); //array of objects with marker details received from backend (will call a, function and set the locations received from the backend)

  const [filteredLocations, setFilteredLocations] = useState([]); //location markers  after filter based on regionChanged event

  const filterLocations = (region) => {
    const filtered = locations?.filter(
      (location) =>
        location?.locationCoordinates.latitude >=
          region?.latitude - region?.latitudeDelta / 2 &&
        location?.locationCoordinates.latitude <=
          region?.latitude + region?.latitudeDelta / 2 &&
        location?.locationCoordinates.longitude >=
          region?.longitude - region?.longitudeDelta / 2 &&
        location?.locationCoordinates.longitude <=
          region?.longitude + region?.longitudeDelta / 2
    );
    setFilteredLocations(filtered);
  };

  const handleRegionChangeComplete = (region) => {
    filterLocations(region, category);
  };

  return (
    <MapView
      ref={mapRef}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 28.7041,
        longitude: 77.1025,
        latitudeDelta: 40,
        longitudeDelta: 40,
      }}
      onRegionChangeComplete={handleRegionChangeComplete}
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
      }}
    >
      {filteredLocations &&
        filteredLocations.map((loc, index) => {
          return (
            <Marker
              key={index}
              identifier={`id${index}`}
              tracksViewChanges={false}
              tracksInfoWindowChanges={false}
              coordinate={{
                latitude: loc.locationCoordinates.latitude,
                longitude: loc.locationCoordinates.longitude,
              }}
              title={loc.name}
              onPress={() => {
                setDirectionPlace(loc.name + ": " + loc.address),
                  setDirectionCoordinate(loc.locationCoordinates),
                  setVisible(true),
                  setLocationId(loc._id);
              }}
              onCalloutPress={() => {
                navigation.pop(),
                  navigation.navigate("ViewLocation", {
                    locationId: loc._id,
                    view: view,
                    categories: category,
                  });
              }}
            >
              <SvgXml xml={loc.icon} />
            </Marker>
          );
        })}
    </MapView>
  );
}
```

**Steps to reproduce**
With the above code after the markers are rendered , try panning the map and one marker will fly from its location to other marker location.

**Expected result**
The marker shall stay at the same location they are supposed to.

**Actual result**
From the attached video you can see that the blue marker flies out to other markers location.

**React Native Maps Version**
0.29.3

**What platforms are you seeing the problem on?**
Android, iOS (Google Maps)

**React Native Version**
0.65.3

**Device(s)**
iPhone 12, Android Oppo A16K

**Additional information**
This seems to happen when the markers are being re-rendered i.e when new data is supplied to the map, this happens on both iOS and Android.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your code. Can you please provide a working code sandbox that demonstrates your issue?